# What are the effects of stopping mitosis?

Tags: biology

What would happen to a human if every cell in their body lost the ability to undergo mitosis, and how quickly would they die?

Comment: As long as meiosis is intact and your human is a male, they'll still be producing gametes. This would only provide minimal solace in their final days

Comment: I imagine quite similar to radiation poisoning.

Comment: @DKNguyen Nothing at all, actually. Radiation poisoning causes damage through necrosis, not just halting mitosis. It would be more similar to very, very heavy chemotherapy than radiation poisoning.

Comment: Corollary question. Could you repair the damage with massive doses of stem cells?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### death in 24-72 hours

real toxins that do this exist, look up miotic inhibitors or for a more direct example Colchicine poisoning.

symptoms of Colchicine overdose, profuse vomiting and diarrhea as the lining for the digestive track breaks down and is not replaced, digestive enzymes start breaking down the actual digestive tract. This leads to fluid loss, pain and sepsis. Hypovolemic shock occurs when new blood stops being produced and circulatory system leaks are not repaired. Stomach lining in particular only lasts about 3 days with no replacement as that is how fast the cells replace themselves. Bone marrow is is even faster with a mitosis rate (doubling time) of less than a day.

While they are dying there are many secondary effects, hair loss, skin slough, widespread organ failure, and even coma.

Colchicine is well studied because overdose happens a lot, but all mitotic inhibitors cause similar effects.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7527738/

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20586571/

[https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/mitotic-inhibitor#:~:text=ATC%20code%20L01CD.-,The%20major%20toxicities%20of%20these%20four%20groups%20are%20bone%20marrow,and%20bleomycin%20cause%20pulmonary%20fibrosis.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/mitotic-inhibitor#:%7E:text=ATC%20code%20L01CD.-,The%20major%20toxicities%20of%20these%20four%20groups%20are%20bone%20marrow,and%20bleomycin%20cause%20pulmonary%20fibrosis.)

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7606322/

Comment: I've never wanted to unknow something more than this.

Comment: @slebetman behold the miracle of biology, you are a series of ongoing processes, interrupt them at your own peril.

Answer (score 11):

Just look at what happens when humans get lethal doses of radiation.

Mitosis stops because the jnstructions on how to do it get garbled up and death happens within days.

Same here, with just less nuisance from the radicals created by the radiation.

Answer (score 8):

## Look at this photograph

[image]

That is Hisashi Ouchi, a technician at a Japanese nuclear plant and one of the people with one of the most tragic stories there is.

What happened to him basically answers your question: Ouchi was exposed to essentially lethal amounts of radiation, and as a result, his white blood cells were thanos'd away and his DNA essentially crumbled down. His cells wouldn't undergo mitosis due to the DNA being heavily damaged, and his skin started to just fall off.
Despite the extreme(ly heartless) efforts of several doctors to keep him alive for as long as they could (despite his several pleads to be allowed to die) he passed away after 83 days due to a fulminating heart attack and multiple organ failure.

Essentially, your body has several portions that undergo constant renovation, and renovation here translates to new cells being formed to replace old ones, your skin constantly renovates it's dead outer layer to keep pathogens out. Your intestines constantly renovate their dinner wall so you can absorb nutrients properly. Your bones and muscles are constantly preparing themselves from the minuscule tears and cracks that natural form from moving. Your blood cells usually live for no more than a month and are also constantly being produced. Etc.

Essentially, your body will slowly shut down as several of your cells just enter senescence and die without other cells to replace them. Your blood will be unable to transport oxygen in no time, you'll be unable to have a proper immune response unless you already have every cell you need for it, your skin will eventually peel down to its living layer and leave you exposed to pathogens (it'll probably also hurt a lot) and may or may not fall off overtime. If acute radiation syndrome is anything to go, you'll probably die in a month at best without doctors constantly providing you with blood transplants and other replacements for your own cells, and since there's no cell division, skin grafts will also not stick.
Essentially, if a person's cells all stopped dividing, they'd likely become the new Mr Ouchi, and would probably last about as long at best.

Comment: As far as I read the report, he was not conscious and thus could not give the required "don't resurrect me" demand that Japanese law set out. The doctors were thus forced to resurrect him when it was possible.

Comment: Is "dinner wall" a medical term I was unaware of, or is that a typo for "inner wall" ?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Either way, it works! The inner wall is where dinner is processed

Answer (score 5):

### At worst days

Assuming that whatever stops it does not instantly kill you, you are suddenly under about the same effects as someone that suffered about [6 to 20 Sievert equivalent dose of acute radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_radiation_syndrome#Dose_effects) and is thrown into the "Walking Ghost Phase" (the latent period) instantly. This phase of Acute Radiation Syndrome takes between minutes to hours (for high doses) to at worst 10 days. Then... the body quite suddenly goes into collapsing as organs fail in rapid succession and they die.

If the equivalent dose is lesser and you apply *tremendous* medical care, you might extend this time to *months*, in which the poor victim may be suffering from his immune system being totally shut down, organs collapsing, and extreme application medicine as well as drugs being necessary to even keep the person alive. In some cases, recovery *can* be possible, but only if the mitosis and cell regeneration does resume. Otherwise, you end up like [Mr. Ouchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokaimura_nuclear_accidents#Nuclear_criticality_event_chronology), [Harry Daghlian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Daghlian) and [Louis Slotin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Slotin). All three were exposed to a lethal dose of radiation. Mr. Ouchi was in part discussed by  [ProjectApex above](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/246383/25822), so let me complete the picture of similar results:

Mr. Ouchi was working on creating the nuclear fuel for a reactor on September 30th 1999, following the handbook to the letter. He was not aware that the handbook contained critical errors and was exceeding safety limits by a factor of 7. The inside of the mixing tanks reached criticality and he was bending over the tank when the event happened. Minutes after the exposure, he vomited, followed by his neurological system malfunctioning. According to the cleanup reports, Mr. Ouchi was hit by 17 Sieverts of radiation. Within hours he fell into a coma with rapid organ failures. Over the next weeks he was repeatedly revived when his heart stopped and finally went into cardiac arrest on December 21st 1999 and could not be revived. His coworker, who only was taking in a dose of 10 Sieverts and rushed to the hospital at the same time died on April 27th 2000 from multiple organ failure.

Mr. Daghlian had to disassemble a nuclear experiment that had reached criticality by hand and thus was exposed to about 5.1 Sieverts on August 21st 1945, while modern estimates place him at a 2 Gray neutron as well as a 1.1 Gray Gamma exposure, before conversion to an equivalent dose. Ultimately, he fell into a coma after the incident and died 25 days after the exposure while on excellent life support (for that time).

Mr. Slotin, was manually performing an experiment (with a screwdriver) on the same material months later on May 21st 1946. Sue to a slip in safety equipment, the exact dose was not recorded. Estimates range from 2.8 to 21 Sieverts. Right after leaving the building, he vomited. Mr. Slotin's initial condition was *satisfactory* on May 25th, despite him directly handling the material. However, he also suffered from radiation burns of his skin and internal organs, "agonizing sequence of radiation-induced traumas", paralysis and many bodily functions failed. After about 7 days he fell into coma and died on May 30th. It is to be presumed, that Mr. Slotin suffered a dose much higher than Mr. Daghlian: modern estimates place his exposure at 10 gray neutrons and 1.14 gray gamma radiation before weighing for equivalent dose.

### At best it is nigh instant death

If you are *lucky*, the only result is that the body... just dies from one moment to the next. Instantly. Why is this the lucky outcome? Because ARS is extremely painful.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody knows really, it is impossible to experiment.

The problems that can be predicted:

- red blood cells live about 3 months, not replacing them is likely to become a problem within a few weeks
- skin and digestive tract, cells are constantly sloughed off and replaced by new ones - likely a few weeks
- cuts, bruises, blisters, etc would stop healing - likely a few weeks.

So, I would say if a person is careful and gets help he would last 1 to 3 weeks.

There are a few answers claiming that radiation "stops mitosis", it is clearly false. Radiation causes direct damages to cells DNA and ionization makes additional cells damage disrupting normal processes in the organism. This is completely different mechanism.

Colchicine overdose mentioned in other answer - again, toxicity is not caused by mitosis inhibition only, the stuff affects multiple key functions of existing cells. It is basically just toxic in large doses.

Comment: Stomach cell lining only lasts a few days with no replacement, your thinking of the intestinal lining or maybe stomach gland cells.

Comment: Radiation absolutely will stop mitosis - it's a simple experiment to do with undergrads and plant seeds - it just does a lot of other things too.

Comment: @Jack Aidley - nope. Feel free to quote Wikipedia or a reliable scientific source. This doesn't follow from anything, there is no any obvious mechanism which would explain it. "A lot of other things" is what radiation-related questions are based on, ray

Comment: @Jack Wikipedia knows nothing about this magic. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_radiation_syndrome for example - not a word about magical "stopped mitosis". "it's a simple experiment to do with undergrads and plant seeds" - it can't be simple for the trivial reason that "it does a lot of other things too".

Comment: I've literally done the experiment. There's no magic here, radiation induces breaks in the chromosomes that prevent the mitotic spindles from correctly forming and separating the newly formed strands.